# Browse pictures on Android and move them to specific directory

Tags: java, android

So I'm building an android application, I want the users to be able to press a button that opens a window/activity. I need the activity to allow the user to browse the pictures saved on the phone and be able to select those that they want. Once they select the pictures and press "ok" the pictures need to be copied to a directory for my application to access them from. So basically does anyone know of any code or help to do this and where would i be able to save user data for my app specifically on the android device. Thanks and let me know if you need any clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting someone to complete your task. Instead of giving solution I would like to suggest you a way to do this, there on you can go and search and find a solution which will make you learn lot of things. Here are some articles where you can have some reading to start with.

1. [Searching files on the android system](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).
2. [Create a view where he can invoke search and select files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)
3. [Storing files on internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Now you need to do some homework and start hitting the keyboard, I'm sure you can do this easily

Comment: Thanks your right i actually figured out how to do it myself i just forgot to delete the question. Sorry for asking for code when i should have done it myself.

Comment: Good to hear peter, way to go.